# Get count by comparing present day to strtotime in database

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a funny question. I want to to get the total count of sales made in a day by a person, whenever the person makes the sale i save it in database as strtotime. now am trying to get the total sales of a person by comparing the present date with what is in the database and getting count of how many of those sales fall into the present day. so far its not working.

```
public function get_sales_today($tab,$id){
    $today = date ('d M,Y',time());
    $todaydate =strtotime($today);
    $que= $this->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM $tab WHERE time_registered ='$todaydate' AND marketer_id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($que);
    return $row['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself a question, what is format for the time_registered in your database

Comment: please tell me which value store in db as time_registered

Comment: its in strtotime looks like this '1485773634'. and its connected to different tables, if i change the format, i will have to change a lot of things @BhavinSasapra

Comment: you have to insert date like 2017-01-30 but i will check other option to make this easier

Comment: ok @hamobi try my code now might it's work for you

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

You have to compare date with db date structure Y-m-d (2017-01-30)

```
public function get_sales_today($tab,$id){
    $today = date ('Y-m-d');
    $que= $this->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM $tab WHERE CAST(time_registered AS date) ='".$today."' AND marketer_id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($que);
    return $row['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: just resulting to 0 as count, even though i have one for today

Comment: now check it's last try from my side. sorry bro check this @hamobi